# Op. amp. with integrator - enough values to start?

Tags: operational-amplifier, schmitt-trigger, integrator

All the red-circled values (Uref, C2, R31 and R36) are missing. I'm supposed to calculate them, but I think there's at least one value missing. Shouldn't Uref be known to calculate the rest of the values?

[image]
The waveform was given beforehand.

The power supply voltages are +/-15V for both op. amps, where the green line is the output of the integrator and blue one is output of the Schmidtt trigger.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not right. You should deduce Uref from the output waveform. It's well possible after you have made it clear how the circuit works in details

Some guidance:

Find how to make the switching levels of the schmitt-trigger to be the extremes of the triangle waveform. You have 2 unknowns (one voltage; one resistor) and 2 voltage division equations.

Then find an integration time constant which makes 15V charging in 2ms with 15V input to be true. You can select integrator's R or C freely, if the parts are ideal. In practice you must obey output current limits and the need to keep the drift low enough.

ADD due the comments. Seemingly you have skipped some basic lessons. Now it's the right time work them.

**Time constant:** The output of the integrator changes just amount -U in time RC, where U=the input voltage of the integrator. You need -15V transition in time 2ms when the input is 15V from U13. RC=2ms is right. 1uF & 2kOhm are ok. Output current 7,5mA isn't impossible for practical opamps altough 0,1uF and 20kOhm would need only 10% of the current.

NOTE: Your Schematic possibly demands that R31=R36. Then you cannot select R31 freely, you must use the value which satisfies the Schmitt trigger's switching levels.

The **Schmitt trigger** (=ST) should flip its output when the integrator output reaches +10V or decays to -5V. In the former case ST's output is -15V until the +10V limit is reached and after it ST's output is +15V until the -5V limit is reached.

See this generalized voltage divider:

[image]

You must be able to prove with elementary DC calculations the formula of Ux in case Ux is not loaded with any current. If you cannot prove this when your teacher wants, you will fail.

Let Ua be the output of the integrator, Ux=the voltage in the plus input of U13 and Ub = the output voltage of U13. We can use Ux's formula if we assume U13 is ideal (= its inputs do not take significant currents and the output really reaches plus and minus 15V)

Now you should write Ux=Uref in two cases: 1) Integrator's output reaches +10V but the ST still outputs -15V.  2) Integrator's output has dropped to -5V but the ST still outputs +15V.

Now you have 2 equations which give Uref and R36.

Comment: Well, this is just an example, from the book of the exercises. This is all I got, but I'm stuck on how to start or how to get the Uref to even properly start the calculating the resistors and cap.

Comment: C2 is connected to the wrong end of R31 in your diagram. The output voltage swing from the integrator is clearly 10V in 2ms, so 5kV/s and the input to the integrator is +-15V (impressive opamp that!), so you can figure the RC product for the integrator resistor and cap. For the comparator, notice that the threshold levels are symmetrical around zero volts, so that tells you what Uref needs to be, then just figure the divider so that with 15V one one end and -5V on the other you hit threshold.

Comment: First of all, I have to apologize. I've corrected both of the pictures, as I've seen I've done mistake on both of them.
On the schematics, I have changed the connection of the capacitor and as on the second, the graph, the positive voltage is +10V (and NOT +5V, as I have had before. I'm horribly sorry for that).

Comment: PS: Can be it assumed, that the Uref is +2.5V? As there is the "middle" of the output of the integrator?

Comment: @E.Wood there is zero room for assumptions. You have 2 voltage division facts for 2 equations and 2 unknowns (Uref and a resistor)

Comment: @user287001: Well, how am I supposed to even start calculating anything?

Is there the t=R*C a good start, where t is determined (2ms) and I can say that the C is 1uF while I calculate the R out? (R=2k)?

Comment: How am I supposed to even start calculating this one?

Comment: @E.Wood some of the elementaries are added to the answer

Comment: Now, if I got this right: U_ref = 2.5V (right? it's the (max-low)/2 which is half, then found the "centre") U_high=+10V U_low=-5V (Right, again?) PS: MADE ANOTHER MISTAKE. R31 and R36 doesn't need to be equal.

Comment: And the thing is, anyhow I turn things around, this excercise seems to be unsolvable (I get different resistance every time I calculate for U+ and U-)

Comment: @E.Wood not unsolvable, Uref=1,67V  and R36=10kOhm. Your work method or more specifically, how to keep all in order, need some service.

Comment: @user287001: Thank you again for the explanation, but I just can't figure it out, WHY should I use Uhigh (hihger input level) and calculate with LOW output level? This just doesn't make sense to me (as this was written in the last sentence of your answer)

Comment: @E.Wood it's in your drawing. Integrator inverts. Integrator's output decreases when schmitt-trigger outputs +15V. Decreasing turns to increasing when integrator's output is low enough (-5V) to flip the ST.